# Script to copy documents and paste them into another folder by name

Tags: python, path, operating-system, document, shutil

I need to write a python script, so that giving a list of document names, it finds them in subfolders of a path, copy them and paste them in another folder.

The problem is that I need the program to also analyze subfolders, as the documents I need are 3 levels below the parent folder.

I have a list of the document names, and would need the script to:

1. Read the name of the first document needed
2. Find it in a set of folders/subfolders
3. Copy the element
4. Paste it to another folder
5. Loop this process with the next document needed.

**Example**:

**1. List with the document names needed:**

documents_to_move = ["49684.32_PJ-R2106027AROJ 1.jpg", "51010.32_PJ-R2206073AZJ 1.jpg"]

**2. Pass a function so that does what needed:**

function(documents_to_move, "\192.168.0.222\Renatta\Renatta 2022\02. WEB\01. WEB FOTOS\02. SUBIDO A WEB")

**3. The function would have to localize these files along the subfolders of the mother folder:**

- 49684.32_PJ-R2106027AROJ 1.jpg -->
  \192.168.0.222\Renatta\Renatta 2022\02. WEB\01. WEB FOTOS\02. SUBIDO A WEB\10. Octubre\2022-10-07_Carlota\BAJA
- 51010.32_PJ-R2206073AZJ 1.jpg -->
  \192.168.0.222\Renatta\Renatta 2022\02. WEB\01. WEB FOTOS\02. SUBIDO A WEB\01. Enero\2022-01-22_Gala&Marta\BAJA

**4. Copy these files, and paste them in a folder in my desktop:** "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\Pablo"

I have tryied these scripts:

```
def find_all(name, path):
result = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if name in files:
        result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
return result
```

and also:

```
def find(pattern, path):
result = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
            result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
return result
```

But both return me an empty list, even if I try with a document which is inside of that path.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Pablo

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you’ve attempted ?

Comment: Yes! I have tryied many things but can not get to where I need. I have edited the question adding the code I have tryied so far

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to use `glob.glob("**/49684.32_PJ-R2106027AROJ 1.jpg', recursive=True)`

Comment: maybe your file has some spaces in name - so you can't see them when you print it but they are don't match to filename on list.

Comment: do you want to follow the same subfolders? or all files just in one folder no matter which subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find your file in the source folder, could be in the main or any subdirectory. It will check if the file is on your list.

Then, if it's on your list, it will print the location of the file and move it.

```
import os
import shutil

def move_function(filestomove, source_input, destination_input):

    fileList = filestomove
    source = source_input
    destination = destination_input

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for file in files: # loops through directories and files
            if file in fileList: # compares to your list
                print(os.path.join(source, file))
                src_path = os.path.join(source, file)
                dst_path = os.path.join(destination, file)
                shutil.copy(src_path , dst_path)
```

Now to run it all you have to do is,

```
documents_to_move = ["49684.32_PJ-R2106027AROJ 1.jpg", "51010.32_PJ-R2206073AZJ 1.jpg"]
source = r'C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\source'
destination = r'C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\Pablo'
move_function(documents_to_move, source, destination)
```

Comment: But could I give it first a list of names, so that it copies them and paste them to the destination folder? Instead of pasting all files?

Comment: the `allfiles` and `files` variable has a list of the files @PabloArizaSuárez replace those with the files you want to move. hold on ill modify.

Comment: @PabloArizaSuárez is this what you meant? The program finds the file in the fileList and moves them to a new location

Comment: The thing is that I dont want all the files from the source, just the ones I have in a list of document names

Comment: @PabloArizaSuárez it will only move the files in the list.

Comment: @PabloArizaSuárez hold on i will make a separate function for you.

Comment: But wil it move them, or will it copy them? I need a copy not to move the original ones. On the other hand, it gives me an error: "name 'f' is not defined"

Comment: this is move, you want copy? hold on

Comment: @PabloArizaSuárez ok it should work the way you want now. please mark my answer with a tick if it helped you.

Comment: Hi @anachy I am using the script and when I run the script it throws me the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/source_folder\\49576.S_Q-R7398JCBBANT 1.jpg' I can see that is mixing "/" with "\"

Comment: Hi @PabloArizaSuárez I have changed my code, I have flipped the slashes, with the r infront of the string it should work. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thankyou!!!!!!!!